# set environment variable on build React.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables, environment

I am trying to have a custom environment variable on build with React, by default it's set to production but I'm trying to have a custom QA build with a custom variable.
***Ps : Project is ejected***, is there anyway I can manage to do that without messing with my webpack configs.

Comment: You can use this: ```new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  "YOUR_VARIABLE": JSON.stringify("value of your variable")
})``` in your webpack config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it (I am using react-scripts) :

In package.json I have those scripts :

```
"build:prototype": "env-cmd -f ./.env.prototype npm run-script build",
"build:demo": "env-cmd -f ./.env.demo npm run-script build",
"build:local": "env-cmd -f ./.env.local npm run-script build",
"build:production": "env-cmd -f .env.production npm run-script build",
```

and I call them just like any other : npm run build:prototype for example

Hope it helps

Edit: of course I have those .env files at the root of the project

Answer (score 0):

Use webpack's [Define Plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)

```html
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  "CUSTOM_VARIABLE": JSON.stringify("whatever you want to set it to")
})
```

And wherever you need to change certain things in your app, you can check the value of `process.env.CUSTOM_VARIABLE` and act according to its value. If there are only a few places that depend on this variable, this will work fine. If there are more, it might be worth looking into other approaches, such as React's [Context Hook API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)